# r ggplot hour format x-axis and reduce spacing of ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, datetime-format

I would like to plot time series of some parameters in a group of plot. the x-axis is very dense.

```
ggplot(Tur_flow, aes(x=time, group=parameter, colour=parameter)) 
  + geom_point(aes(y=value), size=2) + geom_line(aes(y=value), size=1) 
  + stat_smooth(aes(y=value), method=lm, se = TRUE) 
  + facet_grid(parameter ~ Section, scale="free") 
  + theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45),    
        legend.position="bottom") + theme_minimal()[1]

dput(head(Tur_flow))
structure(list(Section = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S-5", "S-50", "S+5", "S+50"), class = "factor"), parameter = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Discharge", "Mean_Velocity", 
"T_15", "T_25", "T_65", "Water_Depth"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 41L), .Label = c("11:59:55", "11:59:56", 
"11:59:58", "11:59:59", "12:00:00", "12:00:02", "12:00:05", "12:00:55", 
"12:00:56", "12:00:58", "12:00:59", "12:01:00", "12:01:01", "12:01:05", 
"12:01:55", "12:01:56............. "8.30", "8.31", "8.41", "8.54", "8.94", "800.31", "822.01", "828.77", "839.30", "846.11", "847.60", "8497.25", "894.21", "91.66", "91.67", "91.68", "91.90", "92.08", "92.23", "92.54", "93.23", "974.50", "N/A"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Section", "parameter", 
"time", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

[image]

How can I reduce the interval to see better the labels.
The format of "time" column is "12:01:55" like or could be "07/10/2014 12:01:55". Which format is compatible for plotting?

Comment: have you looked at library(scales)?

Comment: @MLavoie I've load it, but I didn't know how to use it? Could you tel me how? thanks

Comment: make sure time is in the right format (posixlt) and then use .. + scale_x_datetime() see here for some good examples (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_datetime.html)

Comment: The [scales](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/index.html) website should be able to advise you there

Comment: And if you convert to `POSIXLT`, be sure to attach the (local) time zone. Otherwise it might assume GMT and later convert to your local time zone when plotting. :-(

Comment: @MLavoie, I didn't find why my x-axis is double? also how to reduce the spacing between the ticks? :(

Comment: @RHA Yes it is ok for local time zone.

Comment: to reduce the spacing, use breaks like + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("10 days"))...and what do you mean by x-axis is double?

Comment: @MLavoie, in fact the time series are in less than 1 hour, so I need to show in hour. For double: I mean if you zoom in the plot, in the bottom there is 2 axes (one for each plot and other a general for all plots). I want like y axis.

Comment: you can use scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("15min"))..you can change the break interval

Comment: @MLavoie, ggplot(Tur_flow, aes(x=time, group=parameter, colour=parameter)) + geom_point(aes(y=value), size=2) + geom_line(aes(y=value), size=1) + stat_smooth(aes(y=value), method=lm, se = TRUE) + facet_grid(parameter ~ Section, scale="free") + theme(text = element_text(size=23), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45)) + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position='bottom') + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("15min"), labels=date_format("%d/%m")) Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

Comment: then just use Tur_flow$time <- as.POSIXct(Tur_flow$time, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")  to transform you time variable and it should work.

Comment: @MLavoie, I have done but I got this error:Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: > warnings()
Messages d'avis :
1: Removed 58 rows containing missing values(stat_smooth).2:Removed 83 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).3: Removed 68 rowscontaining missing values (stat_smooth).4: Removed 49 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).5: Removed 58 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).6: Removed 83 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).7: Removed 68 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).8: Removed 49 rows containing missing values (stat_smooth).9: Removed 58 rows containing missing values

Comment: but did you get the plot? I tried to use your dataset but when I copy and paste in my console I get an error message. I don't have access to your full dataset but if if you have NA in dataset it's normal to get those warnings.

Comment: @MLavoie, I solved it by Tur_flow$time <- as.POSIXlt(Tur_flow$time, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") ! thanks a lot for your helps. I changed my time format in csv as exactly d-m-y h:m:s.